# Instagram Messaging API verifications

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

We've been stuck with verification for scope instagram_manage_messages of the IG Messaging API for a long time. We are required to create a test user whose IG business account should be able to receive webhooks and send messages back to the users. But when we try to use our app in development mode to send a message from IG business page through Send API, it throws the following error:

(#100) The thread owner has archived or deleted this conversation, or the thread does not exist.', 'type': 'OAuthException', 'code': 100, 'error_subcode': 2534001

The conversation in question was started by a personal account through which we obtained the conversation ID, and hence should not throw this error.

Can anyone share experiences or guide me through the process on how exactly I can get this scope verified? We're making a mobile app to automate IG messaging for our clients.

Comment: Hello Shambhav,
Did you find answer this issue? i have the same problem my app :(